# Multi-language coreNLP

Tags: stanford-nlp

Is it possible to have more than one Stanford CoreNLP instance, each of them using a different language, in the same Java project?

In the [CoreNLP documentation](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/corenlp.shtml#Download), it seems that the only way to change language is to add a different Maven dependency: what if I want to use all of them together?

Answer (score 1):

If you include a dependency for each language, you will get all of the model files for Chinese, German, and Spanish.  You will now have all the resources to run on Chinese, German, and Spanish.

Within your code, you determine the language by the .properties file you use to build the StanfordCoreNLP pipeline object.  So you are free to build different pipelines with different .properties files.

The appropriate .properties files for the various languages can be found in the corresponding model jars.